# REST query parameters with defaults

Tags: rest

SO i have a URL

1)

```
http://.....api/books?isbn=12345
```

If I want to return all the books, it was suggested i use a string of "ANY"

```
http://...api/books?isbn=ANY
```

But that doesnt sit well with me, lets just say we cant have another URL endpoint, and it has to be this single one. I would be more inclined to either leave it blank and assume its all on Server, or i have another paremeter

```
http://...api/books?Any=true
```

2. 

IF the endpoint responds with two arrays of data, say current and future weather forecasts, would it be better to split that into two endpoints?

```
http://...api/weather?datefrom=20-05-2020&dateto=20-05-2025
```

returns both, past and current and future

Id have thought its better to have

```
http://...api/past/weather?datefrom=datefrom=20-05-2020&dateto=20-05-2025
http://...api/future/weather?datefrom=datefrom=20-05-2020&dateto=20-05-2025
```

or maybe singe one is correct... humm

Whats a good practise, in these instances?

Comment: Overall this is opinion-based, ISBN can be considered a filter (omit it and get everything), and weather is not a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

```
http://...api/books?isbn=ANY
http://...api/books?Any=true
```

Those are both *fine*.

---

> I'd have thought its better to have

Recommendation: don't think about *better*, think about *tradeoffs*.

When you split a single "logical" resource into two, you introduce the possibility that the representations of the two resources will not be consistent with each other (ex: they are views of the data taken at different points in time).

But splitting the resource into two also has advantages - like the fact that you can define different caching policies for them, or 304 - Not Modified a big but stable resource while continuing to provide up to the minute views of the smaller resource.

REST/HTTP doesn't care which design you prefer - it just wants you to use standardized semantics for everything so that general purpose client/caching libraries "just work".